# How to properly and securely handle cookies and sessions in Python's Flask?

Tags: python, security, session, cookies, flask

In application I am writing at the moment I've been saving in users browser a cookie that had session ID stored inside, and that ID was used as a reference to a session stored in the database containing user's information including the fact if the user is logged in properly.

I wanted to review the security of my solution and I stared to look into how I should be setting up cookies upon login, what to store in server side stored session and how to destroy that information on logout since as of now my users were staying logged in for ages, which was not my intention.

The problem I have is no definite answer on how to handle the whole user login/session/logout issue properly in Flask - some people are talking about using Flask's Response.delete_cookie() function, others to expire it using .set_cookie() with zero expiration time, others are mentioning Flask's session module, other itsdangerous module...

What is the most secure, right and proper way of handling that in terms of modules that should be used with Flask, code examples and so on?

Answer (score 29):

## The background

### Method #1

An easy and safe way to handle sessions is to do the following:

- Use a session cookie that contains a session ID (a random number).
- Sign that session cookie using a secret key (to prevent tempering — this is what [itsdangerous](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com) does).
- Store actual session data in a database on the server side (index by ID, or use a NoSQL key / value store).
- When a user accesses your page, you read the data from the database.
- When a user logs out, you delete the data from the database.

Note that there are a few drawbacks.

- You need to maintain that database backend (more maintenance)
- You need to hit the database for every request (less performance)

### Method #2

Another option is to store all the data in the cookie, and sign (and optionally encrypt) said cookie. This method, however, has numerous shortcomings too:

- This is easier on the backend (less maintenance, better performance).
- You need to be careful to not include data your users should not see in sessions (unless you're encrypting).
- The volume of data you can save in a cookie is limited.
- You can't invalidate an individual session (!).

## The code

Flask actually [implements signed session cookies already](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/quickstart/#sessions), so it implements method #2.

To get from #2 to #1, all you have to do is:

- Generate random Session IDs (you could use `os.urandom` + `base64`).
- Save session data in a database backend, indexed by Session ID (serialize it using e.g. JSON, Picke if you need Python objects, but avoid if you can).
- Delete sessions from your database backend when a user logs out.

Make sure you're protected against session fixation attacks. To do so, **make sure you generate a new session ID when a user logs in**, and do not reuse their existing session ID.

Also, make sure you implement expiration on your sessions (just a matter of adding a "last-seen" timestamp).

You could most likely [get some inspiration from Django's implementation](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/sessions/backends).

Comment: I am aware of the pros and cons of these two approaches, and I would rather use the first one, however, my question was mostly about the code examples and modules recommendation, given the desired approach, latest Flask version (that I've read changed handling cookies from Werkzeug to something else) and so on... Care to craft a code example?

Comment: @SpankMe I'm afraid I don't really have time to craft a code example right now. Nonetheless, I added the required steps and gotchas for you.

Comment: This still doesnt address my mentioned doubts about using Flask session module vs itsdangerous, deleting cookies upon logout and so on.

Comment: @SpankMe Flask uses itsdangerous. Deleting cookies is useless so long as you delete (or clear) the session in your backend.

Comment: why is deleting cookies usless? In case of network issues making session deletion impossible, wouldnt deleting cookie save the day and be generally more secure than leaving it?

Comment: @SpankMe Because deleting a cookie and not the backend data when network is unavailable is the equivalent of asking your ex-boy/girlfriend: "I'm sorry, I can't change the lock on my house right now, do you mind throwing your key away instead?". If they want to do bad things to you, they won't trash it (what the user agent does with you asking for the cookie to be deleted is entirely up to them. Same thing for intermediary servers). Once you've changed the lock, you're free to consider it good practice to also ask them to throw the key away, but that doesn't make your house any safer.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt make sense. I am not talking about deleting cookies instead sessions, but about deleting cookies AND sessions so in case of connection issues with the storage backend the whole situation would look a bit more secure, than with the signed cookie left in user's browser.

Comment: @SpankMe I'm not saying you're wrong. All I'm saying is that you **have** to delete / invalidate backend data when someone logs out. If the backend is down, you have to queue that deletion operation, and retry it as soon as the session backend is up again. Deleting the cookie is indeed one extra (albeit very light) layer of security that you could implement, but you must remember that it's not actually safe, and may not actually "save the day". An app is either secure or broken. If you throw your hands up in the air and only delete the cookie if the backend happens to be down, it's broken.

Comment: This is where we are getting back to square one - how should cookies be deleted with Flask?

Comment: @SpankMe Just remove the Session ID from the cookie. Flask will [automatically delete empty session cookies](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L333).

Comment: Could you edit your answer so it would contain all the information we've discussed, so I could upvote it? Otherwise I am afraid it doesnt answer the original post.

Comment: As an aside, the secret key size matters. I've done a bit of research that suggest that a key size of 16 bytes might be inadequate. 32 bytes seems to be adequate for flask. See http://andorian.blogspot.com/2014/08/flask-or-itsdangerous-secret-key-size.html

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you go with the Flask KVSession plugin with the simplekv module to persist the session information.

Conceptually, Flask KVSession provides an implementation for Method #1 described above using the Flask session interface. That way you don't have to alter your code to get it running, and you can use the extension methods to do additional things such as session expiration. It also takes care of the session signing, and does some basic checks to prevent tampering. You will still want to do this over HTTPS to absolutely prevent session stealing however.

Simplekv is the actual module that handles the writing and reading to various data storage formats. This can be as simple as a flat file, as fast as Redis, or as persistent as a database (NoSQL or otherwise). The reason this is a separate module is so Flask KVSession can just be a plain adapter to Flask without having to know about the storage mechanism.

You can find code samples at http://flask-kvsession.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. If you need more examples, I can provide one.

Alternatively, if you need a more enterprise and heavyweight server sided implementation for Flask, you can also look at this recipe using Beaker which works as WSGI middleware (meaning other frameworks also use it). http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/61/. The Beaker API is at http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

One advantage Beaker provides over Flask KVSession is that Beaker will lazy load sessions, so if you don't read the session information, it won't make a connection to the database on every call. However, Beaker depends on SQLAlchemy which is going to be a larger module than simplekv module.

Unless that specific performance case is important, I would still go with Flask KVSession because of its slightly simpler API and smaller code base.